# ParBayesianOptimization suddenly fails while logging epoch results

Tags: r, optimization, hyperparameters

I am currently using the R package `ParBayesianOptimization` to tune parameters for ML methods. While searching for an optimal `cost` parameter for the `svmLinear2` model (contained in `caret`), the optimization stopped with a sudden error after successfully completing 15 iterations.
[image]

Here is the error traceback:

```
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 2 has 9 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 10 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE. 
7.
rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) 
6.
rbind(deparse.level, ...) 
5.
rbind(scoreSummary, data.table(Epoch = rep(Epoch, nrow(NewResults)), 
    Iteration = 1:nrow(NewResults) + nrow(scoreSummary), inBounds = rep(TRUE, 
        nrow(NewResults)), NewResults)) 
4.
addIterations(optObj, otherHalting = otherHalting, iters.n = iters.n, 
    iters.k = iters.k, parallel = parallel, plotProgress = plotProgress, 
    errorHandling = errorHandling, saveFile = saveFile, verbose = verbose, 
    ...) 
3.
ParBayesianOptimization::bayesOpt(FUN = ...
```

So somehow the data tables storing the summary information each iteration suddenly differ in the number of columns present. Is this a common bug with the `ParBayesianOptimization` package? Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Did you find a fix - other than rewriting the `addIterations` function to fill the missing columns?

EDIT:I don't have an explanation for why the error may suddenly occur after a number of successful iterations. However, this issue has reoccurred when using `svmLinear` and `svmRadial`. I was able to reconstruct a similar case with the same error on the `iris` dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)
library(ParBayesianOptimization)
set.seed(1234)

bayes.opt.bounds = list()
bayes.opt.bounds[["svmRadial"]] = list(C = c(0,1000),
                                       sigma = c(0,500))

svmRadScore = function(...){
  grid = data.frame(...)
  mod = caret::train(Species~., data=iris, method = "svmRadial",
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                              number = 7, repeats = 5),
                     tuneGrid = grid)
  return(list(Score = caret::getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainAccuracy"], Pred = 0))
}

bayes.create.grid.par = function(bounds, n = 10){
  grid = data.table()
  params = names(bounds)
  grid[, c(params) := lapply(bounds, FUN = function(minMax){ 
    return(runif(n, minMax[1], minMax[2]))}
  )]
  return(grid)
}

prior.grid.rad = bayes.create.grid.par(bayes.opt.bounds[["svmRadial"]])
svmRadOpt = ParBayesianOptimization::bayesOpt(FUN = svmRadScore,
                                              bounds = bayes.opt.bounds[["svmRadial"]],
                                              initGrid = prior.grid.rad,
                                              iters.n = 100,
                                              acq = "ucb", kappa = 1, parallel = FALSE,plotProgress = TRUE)
```

Using this example, the error occurred on the 9th epoch.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the data used, for a reproducible example? Really hard to tell by just looking at the traceback. Also, provide the calls made to PBO, that would also help.

Comment: @eduardokapp Sadly, I cannot share my original data but I was able to reproduce the error using `svmRadial` on the `iris` dataset.

Comment: Great! I'll look into it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It appears that the scoring function returned `NA`s in place of accuracy measures](https://github.com/AnotherSamWilson/ParBayesianOptimization/issues/33#issuecomment-837013801) leading to the error later downstream. This has been described by the library's creator at

https://github.com/AnotherSamWilson/ParBayesianOptimization/issues/33.

It looks like the SVM is trying a `cost` of `0` during the 9th iteration. Given the problem statement the SVM is solving, the `cost` parameter should probably be positive.

According to [AnotherSamWilson](https://github.com/AnotherSamWilson/ParBayesianOptimization/issues/33#issuecomment-836959347), this error may commonly occur when the scoring function "returns something unexpected".